# issues with discord.py "if channel.id =="

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that takes images from channel A and posts them to channel B when someone reacts to it. I have everything down so far except that it'll also post pictures in channel B if someone reacts to one in channel C. I'm trying to use "if channel.id ==" but so far when I introduce that line the bot will only save the file and will not post anything. any advice would be appreciated

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, channel):
    if reaction.emoji:
        for attachment in reaction.message.attachments:
            filename = attachment.filename
            channel = client.get_channel(560327910179864576)
            await attachment.save(f'imgs/{filename}')
            print("File wrote.")
            if channel.id == 560327910179864576:
                await channel.send(file=discord.File(f'imgs/{filename}'))
                os.remove(f'imgs/{filename}')
```

Comment: _it hasnt been working_ That's too vague.  What, exactly, is it _doing_, and what did you _expect_ it to do instead?

Comment: my bad I should've been more specific. the bot gets to that point and then stops. without the "if channel.id..." line it will post any picture reacted to from any other channel into the specified one. it does not return any errors.

Comment: So you're saying that `client.get_channel(560327910179864576)` can return a channel with a different id?  That seems odd.  Are you sure the id is a number?  Can it be a string instead?

Comment: Try adding an `else` statement for that if, that prints the channel id.  Maybe if you see the id, it might tell you something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `on_reaction_add` doesn't take the `channel` argument, it's `user`
2. `if reaction.emoji` doesn't make sense, it always returns an `discord.Emoji`, `discord.PartialEmoji` or `str`, never `None`, `True` or `False`.
3. You're getting a channel by an id, checking if the channel id is the same as it is doesn't make sense
4. `client.get_channel(id)` doesn't return a boolean so `if client.get_channel` also doesn't make sense
5. You're **saving**, **sending** and then **deleting** a file, you can simply convert it to a `discord.File` object and send it without all that.

Here's your *fixed* code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    """Sends the message attachments to a channel if the
    message is in a specific channel"""

    reaction_channel = reaction.message.channel
    # Checking if the channel is the one want we want
    if reaction_channel.id != your_id:
        # If not, exit
        return

    message = reaction.message
    # Checking if there are any attachments in the message
    if len(message.attachments) == 0:
        # If not, exit
        return

    # Getting the channel
    channel = message.guild.get_channel(some_id) # I'm using `Guild.get_channel` as it is faster than `client.get_channel`
    
    # Iterating through every attachment and sending it to the channel
    for attachment in message.attachments:
        f = await attachment.to_file()
        await channel.send(file=f)
```

Note: You probably want to use `on_raw_reaction_add` instead. `on_reaction_add` it's called if the message is in the internal cache. You also probably want to check if the channel is not a `discord.DMChannel` instance:

```py
is isinstance(reaction_channel, discord.DMCHannel):
    return
```

Comment: thanks for the critique, after applying some of this code into mine its working completely as intended now!